# How to append a NSMutableString with a NSMutableString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSMutableString *str, *str1;
```

//allocation here

i am using 
`[str appendString:str1]` is not working.
`[str appendFormat:str1]` is not working.

So, how to append a `NSMutableString` with another `NSMutableString`.

`@str` is an `empty string` initialize to `nil`. `str1` has some value. `[str appendString str1]` returns `null`

Comment: In order for us to help you, we would need to know what "not working" means in your case, because our crystal ball is currently not working :) According to Apples documentation, both methods should do what you are trying to do ( http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString: )

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Exceptions?

Comment: does not work means not able to append.

Comment: After alloc method, does you call initWithXXX or init, to initialize the variable you allocated ?

Comment: Give an example, please. What is the value of `str` before and after the call?

Comment: @Max, str is an empty string initialize to nil. str1 has some value. [str appendString str1] returns null

Answer (score 21):

Seems like your're sending a message to `nil`. `nil` is **NOT** an object, it's just *nothing*. Sending a message to *nothing* just return *nothing*. In order to append these strings, you need to initialize to an empty string. Like so:

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
```

Then your code will work. Like so:

```
[str appendString:str1];
```

Answer (score 3):

if `str == nil`, no call are performed because there is no object allocated to receive the message but no exception are raised (messages sent to nil return nil by design in Objective-C).

```
NSMutableString *str, *str1;

str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello "];
str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"World"]; 

NSMutableString *sayit = [str appendString:str1];
```

Comment: Then how to set my My NSMutableString to null. Because some point of my program i want to set str1 to empty.

Comment: It's maybe time to explain more precisely what you exactly want to do...  Btw, Empty and nil are different things

Comment: [NSMutableString string] creates an empty mutable string I.e. ""

Answer (score 1):

## Swift version

Although in Swift it is not the general practice to use NSMutableString, [it may at times be necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift). This is how you would do it:

```
var str: NSMutableString = NSMutableString()
var str1: NSMutableString = "some value"
str.appendString(str1 as String) // str = "some value"
```

Note that the usual way to append a string in Swift is like this:

```
var str = ""
let str1 = "some value"
str += str1
```

where `str` and `str1` are inferred to be of type `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *mystring = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"pretty"];
    NSMutableString *appending = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"face"];
    [mystring appendString:appending];
```

works for me...

are you sure the variables have been allocated (correctly?)? No misspellings?