# Working with Unicode code points in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, unicode, mongolian-vertical-script

If you are not interested in the details of Mongolian but just want a quick answer about using and converting Unicode values in Swift, then skip down to the first part of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483262/3681880).

---

## Background

I want to render Unicode text for [traditional Mongolian to be used in iOS apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544714/how-do-you-make-a-vertical-text-uilabel-and-uitextview-for-ios-in-swift). The better and long term solution is to use an [AAT smart font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Advanced_Typography) that would render this complex script. ([Such fonts do exist](http://www.mongolfont.com/en/font/mnglwhiteaat.html) but their license does not allow modification and non-personal use.) However, since I have never made a font, let alone all of the rendering logic for an AAT font, I just plan to do the rendering myself in Swift for now. Maybe at some later date I can learn to make a smart font.

Externally I will use Unicode text, but internally (for display in a `UITextView`) I will convert the Unicode to individual glyphs that are stored in a dumb font (coded with Unicode [PUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) values). So my rendering engine needs to convert Mongolian Unicode values (range: U+1820 to U+1842) to glyph values stored in the PUA (range: U+E360 to U+E5CF). Anyway, this is my plan since it is [what I did in Java in the past](https://github.com/suragch/Chimee/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/chimee/MongolUnicodeRenderer.java), but maybe I need to change my whole way of thinking.

## Example

The following image shows *su* written twice in Mongolian using two different forms for the letter *u* (in red). (Mongolian is written vertically with letters being connected like cursive letters in English.)

[image]

In Unicode these two strings would be expressed as

```
var suForm1: String = "\u{1830}\u{1826}"
var suForm2: String = "\u{1830}\u{1826}\u{180B}"
```

The Free Variation Selector (U+180B) in `suForm2` is recognized (correctly) by Swift `String` to be a unit with the *u* (U+1826) that precedes it. It is considered by Swift to be a single character, an extended grapheme cluster. However, for the purposes of doing the rendering myself, I need to differentiate *u* (U+1826) and FVS1 (U+180B) as two distinct UTF-16 code points.

For internal display purposes, I would convert the above Unicode strings to the following rendered glyph strings:

```
suForm1 = "\u{E46F}\u{E3BA}" 
suForm2 = "\u{E46F}\u{E3BB}"
```

## Question

I have been playing around with Swift `String` and `Character`. There are a lot of convenient things about them, but since in my particular case I deal exclusively with UTF-16 code units, I wonder if I should be using the old `NSString` rather than Swift's `String`. I realize that I can use `String.utf16` to get UTF-16 code points, but [the conversion back to `String` isn't very nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542170/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-string-from-utf16-array-in-swift).

Would it be better to stick with [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html) and [`Character`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Character_Structure/index.html) or should I use [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html) and [`unichar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/unichar)?

## What I have read

- [Strings and Characters documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)
- [Strings in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/)
- [NSString and Unicode](http://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/unicode/)

*Updates to this question have been hidden in order to clean the page up. See the edit history.*

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. `count(string)` gives the number of "extended unicode grapheme clusters", `count(string.utf16)` gives the number of UTF-16 code points required for the same string (which is the length of the corresponding `NSString` or `CFString`). (And `count(string.utf8)` would give the number of UTF-8 code points). – The question *"Should I do something like suForm1.utf16 every time I refer a String?"* cannot be answered generally, it depends on what you need the count for.

Comment: I need to work exclusively (I think) with UTF-16 code points. Counting the length of a string (in UTF-16) is one thing I will need to do, but it is only an example. I will also need to do things like comparing characters (that is UTF-16 code points, not just grapheme clusters that Swift considers equal). Should I use `String` or `NSString` or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "length"... Bytes? Code units? Code points? Grapheme clusters? Pixels? And similarly for "comparing"... Code point equality? Canonical equivalence? Compatibility equivalence?

Comment: UTF-16 code units. I rewrote my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Suragch: I have added another possible solution to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757284/1187415. You probably should work with UInt16/unichar arrays or with NSString as an intermediate representation. Converting NSString to String is actually easy.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

*Updated for Swift 3*

## String and Character

For almost everyone in the future who visits this question, [`String` and `Character`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) will be the answer for you.

**Set Unicode values directly in code:**

```
var str: String = "I want to visit 北京, Москва, मुंबई, القاهرة, and 서울시. "
var character: Character = ""
```

**Use hexadecimal to set values**

```
var str: String = "\u{61}\u{5927}\u{1F34E}\u{3C0}" // a大π
var character: Character = "\u{65}\u{301}" // é = "e" + accent mark
```

Note that the Swift Character can be composed of multiple Unicode code points, but appears to be a single character. This is called an Extended Grapheme Cluster.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284538/how-to-express-strings-in-swift-using-unicode-hexadecimal-values-utf-16) also.

**Convert to Unicode values:**

```
str.utf8
str.utf16
str.unicodeScalars // UTF-32

String(character).utf8
String(character).utf16
String(character).unicodeScalars
```

**Convert from Unicode hex values:**

```
let hexValue: UInt32 = 0x1F34E

// convert hex value to UnicodeScalar
guard let scalarValue = UnicodeScalar(hexValue) else {
    // early exit if hex does not form a valid unicode value
    return
}

// convert UnicodeScalar to String
let myString = String(scalarValue) //
```

Or alternatively:

```
let hexValue: UInt32 = 0x1F34E
if let scalarValue = UnicodeScalar(hexValue) {
    let myString = String(scalarValue)
}
```

A few more examples

```
let value0: UInt8 = 0x61
let value1: UInt16 = 0x5927
let value2: UInt32 = 0x1F34E

let string0 = String(UnicodeScalar(value0)) // a
let string1 = String(UnicodeScalar(value1)) // 大
let string2 = String(UnicodeScalar(value2)) // 

// convert hex array to String
let myHexArray = [0x43, 0x61, 0x74, 0x203C, 0x1F431] // an Int array
var myString = ""
for hexValue in myHexArray {
    myString.append(UnicodeScalar(hexValue))
}
print(myString) // Cat‼
```

Note that for UTF-8 and UTF-16 the conversion is not always this easy. (See [UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465475/how-can-i-create-a-string-from-utf8-in-swift), [UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542170/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-string-from-utf16-array-in-swift), and [UTF-32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421054/convert-uint32-utf-32-to-string-in-swift) questions.)

## NSString and unichar

It is also possible to work with `NSString` and `unichar` in Swift, but you should realize that unless you are familiar with Objective C and good at converting the syntax to Swift, it will be difficult to find good documentation.

Also, `unichar` is a `UInt16` array and as mentioned above the conversion from `UInt16` to Unicode scalar values is not always easy (i.e., converting surrogate pairs for things like emoji and other characters in the upper code planes).

## Custom string structure

For the reasons mentioned in the question, I ended up not using any of the above methods. Instead I wrote my own string structure, which was basically an array of `UInt32` to hold Unicode scalar values.

Again, this is not the solution for most people. First consider using [extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31026358/3681880) if you only need to extend the functionality of `String` or `Character` a little.

But if you really need to work exclusively with Unicode scalar values, you could write a custom struct.

The advantages are:

- Don't need to constantly switch between Types (`String`, `Character`, `UnicodeScalar`, `UInt32`, etc.) when doing string manipulation.
- After Unicode manipulation is finished, the final conversion to `String` is easy.
- Easy to add more methods when they are needed
- Simplifies converting code from Java or other languages

Disadavantages are:

- makes code less portable and less readable for other Swift developers
- not as well tested and optimized as the native Swift types
- it is yet another file that has to be included in a project every time you need it

You can make your own, but here is mine for reference. The hardest part was [making it Hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438210/how-to-implement-the-hashable-protocol-in-swift-for-an-int-array-a-custom-strin).

```
// This struct is an array of UInt32 to hold Unicode scalar values
// Version 3.4.0 (Swift 3 update)


struct ScalarString: Sequence, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    
    fileprivate var scalarArray: [UInt32] = []
    
    
    init() {
        // does anything need to go here?
    }
    
    init(_ character: UInt32) {
        self.scalarArray.append(character)
    }
    
    init(_ charArray: [UInt32]) {
        for c in charArray {
            self.scalarArray.append(c)
        }
    }
    
    init(_ string: String) {
        
        for s in string.unicodeScalars {
            self.scalarArray.append(s.value)
        }
    }
    
    // Generator in order to conform to SequenceType protocol
    // (to allow users to iterate as in `for myScalarValue in myScalarString` { ... })
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<UInt32> {
        return AnyIterator(scalarArray.makeIterator())
    }
    
    // append
    mutating func append(_ scalar: UInt32) {
        self.scalarArray.append(scalar)
    }
    
    mutating func append(_ scalarString: ScalarString) {
        for scalar in scalarString {
            self.scalarArray.append(scalar)
        }
    }
    
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
        for s in string.unicodeScalars {
            self.scalarArray.append(s.value)
        }
    }
    
    // charAt
    func charAt(_ index: Int) -> UInt32 {
        return self.scalarArray[index]
    }
    
    // clear
    mutating func clear() {
        self.scalarArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
    }
    
    // contains
    func contains(_ character: UInt32) -> Bool {
        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar == character {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    // description (to implement Printable protocol)
    var description: String {
        return self.toString()
    }
    
    // endsWith
    func endsWith() -> UInt32? {
        return self.scalarArray.last
    }
    
    // indexOf
    // returns first index of scalar string match
    func indexOf(_ string: ScalarString) -> Int? {
        
        if scalarArray.count < string.length {
            return nil
        }
        
        for i in 0...(scalarArray.count - string.length) {
            
            for j in 0..<string.length {
                
                if string.charAt(j) != scalarArray[i + j] {
                    break // substring mismatch
                }
                if j == string.length - 1 {
                    return i
                }
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    // insert
    mutating func insert(_ scalar: UInt32, atIndex index: Int) {
        self.scalarArray.insert(scalar, at: index)
    }
    mutating func insert(_ string: ScalarString, atIndex index: Int) {
        var newIndex = index
        for scalar in string {
            self.scalarArray.insert(scalar, at: newIndex)
            newIndex += 1
        }
    }
    mutating func insert(_ string: String, atIndex index: Int) {
        var newIndex = index
        for scalar in string.unicodeScalars {
            self.scalarArray.insert(scalar.value, at: newIndex)
            newIndex += 1
        }
    }
    
    // isEmpty
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return self.scalarArray.count == 0
    }
    
    // hashValue (to implement Hashable protocol)
    var hashValue: Int {
        
        // DJB Hash Function
        return self.scalarArray.reduce(5381) {
            ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ Int($1)
        }
    }
    
    // length
    var length: Int {
        return self.scalarArray.count
    }
    
    // remove character
    mutating func removeCharAt(_ index: Int) {
        self.scalarArray.remove(at: index)
    }
    func removingAllInstancesOfChar(_ character: UInt32) -> ScalarString {
        
        var returnString = ScalarString()
        
        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar != character {
                returnString.append(scalar)
            }
        }
        
        return returnString
    }
    func removeRange(_ range: CountableRange<Int>) -> ScalarString? {
        
        if range.lowerBound < 0 || range.upperBound > scalarArray.count {
            return nil
        }
        
        var returnString = ScalarString()
        
        for i in 0..<scalarArray.count {
            if i < range.lowerBound || i >= range.upperBound {
                returnString.append(scalarArray[i])
            }
        }
        
        return returnString
    }
    
    
    // replace
    func replace(_ character: UInt32, withChar replacementChar: UInt32) -> ScalarString {
        
        var returnString = ScalarString()
        
        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar == character {
                returnString.append(replacementChar)
            } else {
                returnString.append(scalar)
            }
        }
        return returnString
    }
    func replace(_ character: UInt32, withString replacementString: String) -> ScalarString {
        
        var returnString = ScalarString()
        
        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar == character {
                returnString.append(replacementString)
            } else {
                returnString.append(scalar)
            }
        }
        return returnString
    }
    func replaceRange(_ range: CountableRange<Int>, withString replacementString: ScalarString) -> ScalarString {
        
        var returnString = ScalarString()
        
        for i in 0..<scalarArray.count {
            if i < range.lowerBound || i >= range.upperBound {
                returnString.append(scalarArray[i])
            } else if i == range.lowerBound {
                returnString.append(replacementString)
            }
        }
        return returnString
    }
    
    // set (an alternative to myScalarString = "some string")
    mutating func set(_ string: String) {
        self.scalarArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        for s in string.unicodeScalars {
            self.scalarArray.append(s.value)
        }
    }
    
    // split
    func split(atChar splitChar: UInt32) -> [ScalarString] {
        var partsArray: [ScalarString] = []
        if self.scalarArray.count == 0 {
            return partsArray
        }
        var part: ScalarString = ScalarString()
        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar == splitChar {
                partsArray.append(part)
                part = ScalarString()
            } else {
                part.append(scalar)
            }
        }
        partsArray.append(part)
        return partsArray
    }
    
    // startsWith
    func startsWith() -> UInt32? {
        return self.scalarArray.first
    }
    
    // substring
    func substring(_ startIndex: Int) -> ScalarString {
        // from startIndex to end of string
        var subArray: ScalarString = ScalarString()
        for i in startIndex..<self.length {
            subArray.append(self.scalarArray[i])
        }
        return subArray
    }
    func substring(_ startIndex: Int, _ endIndex: Int) -> ScalarString {
        // (startIndex is inclusive, endIndex is exclusive)
        var subArray: ScalarString = ScalarString()
        for i in startIndex..<endIndex {
            subArray.append(self.scalarArray[i])
        }
        return subArray
    }
    
    // toString
    func toString() -> String {
        var string: String = ""
        
        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if let validScalor = UnicodeScalar(scalar) {
                string.append(Character(validScalor))
            }
        }
        return string
    }
    
    // trim
    // removes leading and trailing whitespace (space, tab, newline)
    func trim() -> ScalarString {
        
        //var returnString = ScalarString()
        let space: UInt32 = 0x00000020
        let tab: UInt32 = 0x00000009
        let newline: UInt32 = 0x0000000A
        
        var startIndex = self.scalarArray.count
        var endIndex = 0
        
        // leading whitespace
        for i in 0..<self.scalarArray.count {
            if self.scalarArray[i] != space &&
                self.scalarArray[i] != tab &&
                self.scalarArray[i] != newline {
                
                startIndex = i
                break
            }
        }
        
        // trailing whitespace
        for i in stride(from: (self.scalarArray.count - 1), through: 0, by: -1) {
            if self.scalarArray[i] != space &&
                self.scalarArray[i] != tab &&
                self.scalarArray[i] != newline {
                
                endIndex = i + 1
                break
            }
        }
        
        if endIndex <= startIndex {
            return ScalarString()
        }
        
        return self.substring(startIndex, endIndex)
    }
    
    // values
    func values() -> [UInt32] {
        return self.scalarArray
    }
    
}

func ==(left: ScalarString, right: ScalarString) -> Bool {
    return left.scalarArray == right.scalarArray
}

func +(left: ScalarString, right: ScalarString) -> ScalarString {
    var returnString = ScalarString()
    for scalar in left.values() {
        returnString.append(scalar)
    }
    for scalar in right.values() {
        returnString.append(scalar)
    }
    return returnString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Swift 3.0  
// This struct is an array of UInt32 to hold Unicode scalar values
struct ScalarString: Sequence, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {

    private var scalarArray: [UInt32] = []

    init() {
        // does anything need to go here?
    }

    init(_ character: UInt32) {
        self.scalarArray.append(character)
    }

    init(_ charArray: [UInt32]) {
        for c in charArray {
            self.scalarArray.append(c)
        }
    }

    init(_ string: String) {

        for s in string.unicodeScalars {
            self.scalarArray.append(s.value)
        }
    }

    // Generator in order to conform to SequenceType protocol
    // (to allow users to iterate as in `for myScalarValue in myScalarString` { ... })

    //func generate() -> AnyIterator<UInt32> {
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<UInt32> {

        let nextIndex = 0

        return AnyIterator {
            if (nextIndex > self.scalarArray.count-1) {
                return nil
            }
            return self.scalarArray[nextIndex + 1]
        }
    }

    // append
    mutating func append(scalar: UInt32) {
        self.scalarArray.append(scalar)
    }

    mutating func append(scalarString: ScalarString) {
        for scalar in scalarString {
            self.scalarArray.append(scalar)
        }
    }

    mutating func append(string: String) {
        for s in string.unicodeScalars {
            self.scalarArray.append(s.value)
        }
    }

    // charAt
    func charAt(index: Int) -> UInt32 {
        return self.scalarArray[index]
    }

    // clear
    mutating func clear() {
        self.scalarArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
    }

    // contains
    func contains(character: UInt32) -> Bool {
        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar == character {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    // description (to implement Printable protocol)
    var description: String {

        var string: String = ""

        for scalar in scalarArray {
            string.append(String(describing: UnicodeScalar(scalar))) //.append(UnicodeScalar(scalar)!)
        }
        return string
    }

    // endsWith
    func endsWith() -> UInt32? {
        return self.scalarArray.last
    }

    // insert
    mutating func insert(scalar: UInt32, atIndex index: Int) {
        self.scalarArray.insert(scalar, at: index)
    }

    // isEmpty
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        get {
            return self.scalarArray.count == 0
        }
    }

    // hashValue (to implement Hashable protocol)
    var hashValue: Int {
        get {

            // DJB Hash Function
            var hash = 5381

            for i in 0 ..< scalarArray.count {
                hash = ((hash << 5) &+ hash) &+ Int(self.scalarArray[i])
            }
            /*
             for i in 0..< self.scalarArray.count {
             hash = ((hash << 5) &+ hash) &+ Int(self.scalarArray[i])
             }
             */
            return hash
        }
    }

    // length
    var length: Int {
        get {
            return self.scalarArray.count
        }
    }

    // remove character
    mutating func removeCharAt(index: Int) {
        self.scalarArray.remove(at: index)
    }
    func removingAllInstancesOfChar(character: UInt32) -> ScalarString {

        var returnString = ScalarString()

        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar != character {
                returnString.append(scalar: scalar) //.append(scalar)
            }
        }

        return returnString
    }

    // replace
    func replace(character: UInt32, withChar replacementChar: UInt32) -> ScalarString {

        var returnString = ScalarString()

        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar == character {
                returnString.append(scalar: replacementChar) //.append(replacementChar)
            } else {
                returnString.append(scalar: scalar) //.append(scalar)
            }
        }
        return returnString
    }

    // func replace(character: UInt32, withString replacementString: String) -> ScalarString {
    func replace(character: UInt32, withString replacementString: ScalarString) -> ScalarString {

        var returnString = ScalarString()

        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar == character {
                returnString.append(scalarString: replacementString) //.append(replacementString)
            } else {
                returnString.append(scalar: scalar) //.append(scalar)
            }
        }
        return returnString
    }

    // set (an alternative to myScalarString = "some string")
    mutating func set(string: String) {
        self.scalarArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        for s in string.unicodeScalars {
            self.scalarArray.append(s.value)
        }
    }

    // split
    func split(atChar splitChar: UInt32) -> [ScalarString] {
        var partsArray: [ScalarString] = []
        var part: ScalarString = ScalarString()
        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            if scalar == splitChar {
                partsArray.append(part)
                part = ScalarString()
            } else {
                part.append(scalar: scalar) //.append(scalar)
            }
        }
        partsArray.append(part)
        return partsArray
    }

    // startsWith
    func startsWith() -> UInt32? {
        return self.scalarArray.first
    }

    // substring
    func substring(startIndex: Int) -> ScalarString {
        // from startIndex to end of string
        var subArray: ScalarString = ScalarString()
        for i in startIndex ..< self.length {
            subArray.append(scalar: self.scalarArray[i]) //.append(self.scalarArray[i])
        }
        return subArray
    }
    func substring(startIndex: Int, _ endIndex: Int) -> ScalarString {
        // (startIndex is inclusive, endIndex is exclusive)
        var subArray: ScalarString = ScalarString()
        for i in startIndex ..< endIndex {
            subArray.append(scalar: self.scalarArray[i]) //.append(self.scalarArray[i])
        }
        return subArray
    }

    // toString
    func toString() -> String {
        let string: String = ""

        for scalar in self.scalarArray {
            string.appending(String(describing:UnicodeScalar(scalar))) //.append(UnicodeScalar(scalar)!)
        }
        return string
    }

    // values
    func values() -> [UInt32] {
        return self.scalarArray
    }

}

func ==(left: ScalarString, right: ScalarString) -> Bool {

    if left.length != right.length {
        return false
    }

    for i in 0 ..< left.length {
        if left.charAt(index: i) != right.charAt(index: i) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

func +(left: ScalarString, right: ScalarString) -> ScalarString {
    var returnString = ScalarString()
    for scalar in left.values() {
        returnString.append(scalar: scalar) //.append(scalar)
    }
    for scalar in right.values() {
        returnString.append(scalar: scalar) //.append(scalar)
    }
    return returnString
}
```

Comment: I think using `String(describing:UnicodeScalar(scalar))` produces Strings with "Optional" written in them. See the update to my answer for a better method.