# Messaging : Support Emijo between Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, unicode, swift2

I'm creating an app for to sending messages from one user to another user.

This app is developed in Android and iOS (swift 2.2).

In Android I'm using `org.apache.commons` to encode / decode string to Unicode using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` and `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava`
Encoding method gave me this result (for a string containing emojis) :

`Hello \uD83E\uDD23`

This is impossible to decode this in Swift.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift), I think iOS need this String as input to correct decode it :

`Hello \u{D83E}\u{DD23}`

Is there an easy way to make iOS and Android compatible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution :

```
static func decode(input: String) -> String? {
    let ns = NSString(string: input)
    let data:NSData = ns.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    return NSString(data:data,encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding) as? String
}
```