# Show emojis in push notifcation on ios sent via apn node module

Tags: ios, node.js, emoji, apn

I am sending push notification to ios devices via node package Apn.

The notification title are not showing the emojis, the encoded string is being displayed as it is.

I have checked other solutions but i could not find any working solution so far.
Have tried to send the encoding 'ucs2' as well but it didn't work in my case

`var message = '\uD83D\uDCE7 \u2709 heavy rain\\uD83D\\uDCA6\\uD83D';`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift

Comment: @SachinVas  Is this not a server side problem while sending the push notification.
May be i am wrong but this is what i think so far

Comment: Who is creating and sending the message? If it is you, make sure the message contains Unicode Code Points.