# Saving a string with unicode characters to CoreData fails

Tags: swift, core-data

I am getting a bunch of data from an API call which returns an array of items, each item has an array of content elements where each content has a string element and an optional image element.

This works most of the times. But if the string has unicode characters being returned from the server, when I try to save them to CoreData, it results in a CoreData fault.

For instance, one of the content elements' string returns `\U2666\U2666\U2666` from the server. When I set this in contentElement.text, and do an moc.save(), it results in a data fault.

I am able to save strings with swift unicode format `\u{xxxx}` to CoreData, but not these "web-based" unicode chars. Is there any way to convert the unicode chars to swift format without using regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift

Comment: What do you mean by "data fault"? "Fault" is a normal thing in Core Data so it's not clear what problem(s) you are seeing.

Comment: The object is not saved to coredata. moc.save doesn't give any errors but the object returned is a nil?