# How to append two NSMutableAttributeString in swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablestring, nsmutableattributedstring

how to join two NSMutableAttributeString into single NSMutableAttributeString in swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31390761/1311272 does that help?

Comment: sorry guys,NSMutableAttributeString how can i add two into single?

Answer (score 1):

Simple try this:

```
let a = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello")
let b = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "world!")
a.appendAttributedString(b)

print("final string =\(a)")
```

Comment: how can i convert two NSMutableAttributeStrings into single NSMutableAttributeString

Comment: Check edited answer.

Comment: The question is tagged "swift".

Comment: Edited answer checkout

Comment: working fine,thanks @NagaArjun

Comment: @Eric D Answered for swift you may upvote now

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer, @Nagarjun.